# RJ45 Wall Outlets Prioritizing Modem DHCP

Tags: networking

I want to start off by saying that I'm not sure the title is 100% correct, but that's what I suspect is happening.

My problem is that after plugging an ethernet cable into any of the wall outlets in my apartment, my [router](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/rt-ac68p/helpdesk_bios/) is not seen by any devices.
[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt0Q0.png)

The [modem](https://www.goamt.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/7342_ISAM_ONT_I-241G-B_AMT.pdf) is from my ISP and has a built-in switch (I think) however, I cannot figure out if I'm able to configure it. It appears to be in bridge mode, as only LAN1 outputs a signal, although I have no way to confirm that. I initially thought of moving my router into the network panel where the modem is however, it is not large enough to fit. Moving the router is also not really an option because I have two servers running on a UPS, along with the router, that need to stay online with each other.

After looking into configuring the modem, to no avail, one of my more networking-savvy friends suggested that I get a managed switch and set up a vlan for the specific wall outlet where my router is.  I then purchased a [TL-SG105E](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/easy-smart-switch/tl-sg105e/v5/) (tldr very basic tp link managed switch with vlan capabilities) and got to work setting it up.  I was able to configure the switch when connecting it directly into my router, but as soon as I go to replace the existing switch, I am no longer able to configure it because it doesn't hit my routers DHCP.

Any ideas? Or anything that I'm overlooking?

Edit: I also realize that getting another router to put in the network panel in place of the switch is an option however, I'm trying to minimize cost here.  I will explore that route if I absolutely have to.

Comment: It helps a *lot* to actually draw out your network physically - especially in terms of ports and physical connections so others can 'see' your network. Home networks can get amazingly convoluted and it might be helpful. I don't think you need another router, but the arrangement is specific. Few things I'd add here is your 'modem' is an ONT. Some ISPs either set up more than 1 wan connection or set it in ONR mode. Treat it as a ethernet uplink. You *do* need your router connected to the modem via the wan port, and others to the router. You can reorganise it though

Comment: Thank you, I will add an image.  I figured that everything would have to be connected through the routers wan port, but I would really like to find out if there is a possible configuration, using a vlan or perhaps other hardware, that would allow all the ethernet wall outlets to function.

Comment: I believe you're essentially trying to build a router on a stick type config, which *unfortunately* I am unfamiliar with.  Its a starting point though

Comment: Thank you! I will continue to doing research

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Using your insight I was able to find a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fios/comments/iydkew/putting_a_switch_between_ont_and_router/) with a nearly identical scenario.  There appears to be some hope with a vlan, so I will pursue that further.

Answer (score 1):

> as soon as I go to replace the existing switch, I am no longer able to configure it because it doesn't hit my routers DHCP.

Sounds like you're connecting it to the router's "WAN" interface, which is not configured to serve DHCP in the first place (it only has a DHCP *client* running on that interface to get an IP address from the ISP).

In this kind of setup, your switch needs to be connected to **both** the "LAN" and "WAN" interfaces of the router, on separate VLANs. If your router also supports VLANs, then this could be a single Ethernet cable with either LAN or WAN (or both) configured as "tagged" 802.1Q VLANs. If the router has no VLAN support, however, then you will need two Ethernet cables (and two switch ports) for the router connection.

(Hardware-wise I'm pretty sure most home wifi routers could support VLANs, as that's how the "WAN" port is often implemented… but most of them don't offer it in their setup pages.)

It is not enough to merely put the router in a separate VLAN alone, as there still has to be something that routes packets between the two VLANs, and that would be… a router. With practically every kind of VLAN setup, it is necessary to have a device that has access to multiple VLANs at once and routes between them.

---

Note: Because VLANs are functionally separate interfaces carrying different networks, your switch will also have an IP address associated with a specific VLAN (like a regular host would). As far as I know, the TL-SG105E will only speak DHCP on VLAN 1, therefore you should choose VLAN 1 to be your `LAN` VLAN.

(Better managed switches (such as TP-Link's JetStream series) would allow selecting the "management" VLAN that they'll get an IP in – or even allow their IP addresses to be configured independently for each VLAN – but TL-SG105E is *very* basic.)

Comment: I assume this wouldnt work/isnt good practice, but could I run the network panel cable (center line on diagram) to the switch on my router, then loop another port on the switch to the WAN interface?

Comment: On which switch – the router's or the one at the network panel?

Comment: The routers switch

Comment: Without VLAN tagging it's not going to work; that's how you _create_ the problem you've described in the title – you'd be merging both (and bringing both DHCP servers) into the same L2 network, and you don't want that because there really is no way to "prioritize" one DHCP server. Such a connection would be useful _only_ if the router supports VLAN tagging at least on the WAN interface (assuming it doesn't offer full VLAN trunking configuration), and then I'm not sure if its LAN switch wouldn't mess up the tag (because internally the WAN port is often just a hidden VLAN on the same switch...)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a minimum viable configuration for testing before looking at vlans

[image]
 <sub><sup>apologies for the odd format - Its what I use for my own docs</sup></sub>

My recommendation is to get this working *first*.

Now there's a few things to consider here. You don't need DHCP to get internet - DHCP is *one* of many things a consumer router does.

A consumer router is a firewall (critically doing IP masquerading), router (connecting 2 networks), DHCP server (which can be elsewhere on your network) and access point. You really need to think about the first two. I THINK the failure's really in the topology rather than DHCP.

I also believe your *router* needs to be vlan aware (or need an additional smart switch), and you'd essentially be using vlans to replicate this set up - running the connection from the ONT over a vlan to the router, then back to the switch.

If not you need 2 vlan enabled switches, with one line connecting the two, and the appropriate vlans set. I *believe* you'd want to set the port connecting the two switches as a trunk,and one port on each switch on a vlan, but I'm not entirely sure.

Still, I do believe you're looking at the problem at the 'wrong' place.